# Bootstrap doen't work on Mini Opera (iOS)

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm using Bootstrap styles on my project (http://getbootstrap.com/). It's made in Symphony 2. Everything is working fine on Windows (Opera, Firefox, Chrome), on iOS it's fine for example on Safari but on Mini Opera it just not working fine. Some styles are loaded, like backgrounds, colors. But for example glaphicons are not shown, modals doesn't open (when I click button that should open modal window site is only refresing...). The same with dropdowns.
Any ideas how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opera Mini doesn't support font-face

http://caniuse.com/fontface

Bootstrap doesn't support non-desktop Opera

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10571

So unfortunately, it looks like you will need to find some workarounds.